# Mounting NTFS hard drive on boot

Tags: mount, boot, hard-disk, fstab

I am trying to mount a hard drive with an NTFS filesystem on it on boot.

It doesn't need a special location. /mnt/ or something similar should be enough.

I had already done that with a drive but it is way back and i can't remember how I did it. Also I am too scared to just go dive into the fstab file.

I am on the latest Arch Linux 64 bit version

The drive is called /dev/sda1 (idk if thats important)

Comment: Warning: If your NTFS partition is left in an inconsistent (or non-working) state by some other operating system, your boot will never complete. Mount it later, with  a `root` `@reboot` cron job.

Comment: how do you mean?

how else should i mount it? over a script thats executed at startup? i dont quite get you i think. why would a partition thats just only data completely wreck my boot tho?

Comment: Read `less /etc/crontab;man -a crontab`. By starting your NTFS mount (which may have been made un-writeable by Windows) in a `cron` job, if the `mount` fails to complete, only a `cron` job hangs (and the `cron` daemon knows how to handle `cron` jobs that hang). If you mount the disk during system startup and, again, the `mount` fails to complete, your system startup will hang. This system startup hang is hard to diagnose, and requires a Live USB to remove the NTFS drive from `fstab` to get a failing system to boot

Comment: well ok seems easy enough to fix. if i have boot problems i will remember that thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend reading the [fstab article on Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/fstab), it's very good, but you don't really need that much, if your NTFS partition is `/dev/sda1` all you need to add is this line

```
/dev/sda1  /mnt/<name>   ntfs   defaults  0 0
```

you don't really anything more that that.

You can also configure fstab from GUI using GNOME Disks. Select the NTFS partition, click one the *Additional partition options* icon and select *Edit Mount options* and then simply enable *Mount at system startup*, rest of the fields should be pre-filled with some reasonable defaults.

[image]

Comment: u truly are a hero, ty. i used the option over the GUI as i did not want to fiddle with the fstab (i alr had but it was a complete mess of conflicting informations in forums and i think i am lucky i didnt break stuff)

Answer (score 0):

(can not add comments)

other idea (which may helps): libpammount to mount after a login

Comment: thank you for the heads up. my problem is already solved but someone who may stumble across this may find it helpful. :)

Comment: also to mention: in the past activ ntfs mounts slowes down the system. i dont know if yet exists but thats why i choose that way (first) then a manual mount until i dont need ntfs anymore